# Computer shuts down many times between each Windows session

Tags: boot, windows-10, reboot

Upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 with a clean install, and the following behavior is now happening every time I turn it on :

- computer is shut down in Windows
- next time it is turned on, it won't show BIOS and lit <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>, just a non-blinking cursor
- computer turns off, does that 2 to 3 times in a row
- finally the computer starts properly and loads Windows

Not that after fresh installation it did not happen, it started once I configured it (drivers, software)

Looking at the event viewer I can see this ***ATIeRecord:*** ATI EEU PnP start/stop failed, however I couldn't find much info about it on the web.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What information there is suggests that it is a issue with the ATI GPU drivers. See if the manufacturer of your PC has updated drivers on their website.

Comment: Well, already did that and it is the latest version :(

Comment: Did you check the ATI website as well?

Comment: Yes of course, by the way I've also checked Windows Update and obviously it tells they are the latest ones ... I'm starting to think that some people will invariably get affected by Win10 bugs since it's a really new product.

Comment: Look that way. It seems a lot of people are waiting for updated ATI drivers.

Comment: Yes, definitely. There are some people suggesting turning EnableULPS off in registry about this issue but I don't really feel it's a good fix... Anyway, thanks for your help !

Comment: Apparently that just turns off the event being logged - it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: The problem has grown since this afternoon and I've learned a bit more about it : motherboard (guess). Basically I am now running with only 1 RAM stick as no matter what I do with multiple sticks it always fails XD. Been updating the BIOS and slowly testing ... crossing my fingers. It is extremely annoying in the sense that I have work to do and cannot afford waiting for RMA or whatever, if I could precisely know what's faulty I'd replace it and RMA the old component (if it's still under warranty).

Comment: I'm having this same problem since windows 8.1, I don't know if is my motherboard or my graphic card, both are out of warranty and expensive enough to make think about change any component.

Comment: Progressed a bit, it seems to be the MB, removed/plugged things 1 by 1 until finding that only 1 RAM stick works. HOWEVER, :D since I left GPU and RAM unplugged for a day and plugged things back in, it started working again, though I've only put in 2 sticks. Rough guess it might be due to some static. Been in touch with Gigabyte and they didn't even ask a question but told me to send it back so I guess they know it's faulty by the symptoms described, so I'll do it soon. BTW this guide has been handy : http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/261145-31-perform-steps-posting-post-boot-video-problems